# Cannot Solve: Map an array of objects to a button element (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, functional-programming

So I facing difficulty in creating an a set of buttons using the map method. What I have done is create an array of objects with the button id, src etc and would like to map this array on to my buttons.

It keeps telling the variable is undefined and throws an error. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Here’s my code so far:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";

const sounds = [
  {
    idnum: "1",
    id: "Q",
    src: "1.html",
  },
  {
    idnum: "1",
    id: "W",
    src: "",
  },
  {
    idnum: "1",
    id: "E",
    src: "",
  },
  {
    idnum: "1",
    id: "A",
    src: "",
  },
  {
    idnum: "1",
    id: "S",
    src: "",
  },
  {
    idnum: "1",
    id: "D",
    src: "",
  },
  {
    idnum: "1",
    id: "Z",
    src: "",
  },
  {
    idnum: "1",
    id: "X",
    src: "",
  },
  {
    idnum: "1",
    id: "C",
    src: "",
  },
];

class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const buttonData = this.sounds.map((info) => (
      <button>
        {info[id]}+{info[idnum]}
      </button>
    ));

    return { buttonData };
  }
}
export default Button;
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can get the ```sounds``` array by simply using ```sound.map``` not ```this.sounds.map```

Comment: Hi, I tried it. Heres the error its throwing up: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {buttonData}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using codesandbox or codepen or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong way for accessing, either use string in bracess of use .(dot) operator.

```
render() {
    const buttonData = this.sounds.map((info) => (
      <button>
        {info.id}+{info.idnum}
      </button>
    ));

    return { buttonData };
  }
```

Or

```
render() {
    const buttonData = sounds.map((info) => (
      <button>
        {info["id"]}+{info["idnum"]}
      </button>
    ));

    return { buttonData };
  }
```

Entire: https://codepen.io/deepakshrma/pen/ZEbYBPm?editors=1111

```
// import React from "react";
// import ReactDom from "react-dom";

const sounds = [
  {
    idnum: "1",
    id: "Q",
    src: "1.html",
  },
  {
    idnum: "1",
    id: "W",
    src: "",
  },
  {
    idnum: "1",
    id: "E",
    src: "",
  },
  {
    idnum: "1",
    id: "A",
    src: "",
  },
  {
    idnum: "1",
    id: "S",

    src: "",
  },
  {
    idnum: "1",
    id: "D",
    src: "",
  },
  {
    idnum: "1",
    id: "Z",
    src: "",
  },
  {
    idnum: "1",
    id: "X",
    src: "",
  },
  {
    idnum: "1",
    id: "C",
    src: "",
  },
];

class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const buttonData = sounds.map((info, i) => (
      <button>
        {info["id"]}+{info["idnum"]}
      </button>
    ));
    return (<>{buttonData}</>)
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Button />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Hi, so i tried both and the error I am getting is TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. When I remove "this" - the error is Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {buttonData}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: @Pruthvi Please create a small demo for this. There must be something here that we are missing.

Comment: why you are using this. sound is not part od class. i updated sol.

Comment: @palaѕн https://codepen.io/pruthvi-ashok/pen/MWaYbqB?editors=0010 - I hope this is fine.

Comment: @xdeepakv I tried by removing this too and it showed a different error.

Comment: Bro u are writing jsx, not js. You need babel` comipler `to convert` jsx to js`.

Comment: @Pruthvi i have updated solution with codepen.io link

Comment: @xdeepakv Sorry bro, I was working in vs code and so couldnt put the babel compiler. I even tried the solution you put up now. Its throwing the following: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: @xdeepakv Superb bro! Just saw your codepen. Thanks for the help!